# Contact Form 7 and FPDF

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have been following several topics on wordpress.org about saving the data submitted in Contact Form 7 and sending it to the the submitter as a PDF attachment.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/convert-pdf-file

[Exporting form results from Contact form 7 to PDF (fPDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094291/exporting-form-results-from-contact-form-7-to-pdf-fpdf)

Im using Kory's php in my functions and have uploaded fpdf to me theme file in a folder called fpdf plus added in [attachments] to my contact form in wordpress admin.

My error is that the contact form doesn't submit. Just loads. Any ideas?

My Form - http://www.mikeandtom.co.uk/ctest

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_update_email_body');
function wpcf7_update_email_body($contact_form) {

$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if ( $submission ) {
/* DEFINE CONSTANT AND GET FPDF CLASSES */
define ('FPDF_PATH',get_template_directory().'/fpdf/'); // MAKE SURE THIS POINTS      TO THE DIRECTORY IN YOUR THEME FOLDER THAT HAS FPDF.PHP 
require(FPDF_PATH.'fpdf.php');

$posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
// SAVE FORM FIELD DATA AS VARIABLES 
$name = $posted_data["your-name"];

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Write(5,$name);
$pdf->Output(FPDF_PATH.'test.pdf', 'F'); // OUTPUT THE NEW PDF INTO THE SAME   DIRECTORY DEFINED ABOVE

}
}

add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components' );
function mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components($components){
if (empty($components['attachments'])) {
$components['attachments'] = array(FPDF_PATH .'test.pdf'); // ATTACH THE NEW PDF    THAT WAS SAVED ABOVE
}
return $components;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on submission: `<b>FPDF error:</b> Could not include font definition file`.

Comment: changed arial font to courier as that is included in fphp and still no joys

Comment: Still getting the error: `<b>FPDF error:</b> Undefined font: times-roman B`. I think there is something wrong with the way you're loading the font files (regardless of which font you're loading).

Comment: @vicente what are you using to generate the error? I cant replicate at all for some reason

Comment: I'm using firebug (https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/). When you submit the form, you can see the error in the console tab.

Comment: So work arounds included adding font by defining the font definition file but this just threw up a 'could not define font definition file'  `define('FPDF_FONTPATH',get_template_directory().'fpdf/font/');
define ('FPDF_PATH',get_template_directory().'/fpdf/'); // MAKE SURE THIS POINTS TO THE DIRECTORY IN YOUR THEME FOLDER THAT HAS FPDF.PHP
require(FPDF_PATH.'fpdf.php');`