# Customize content and export in a PDF

Tags: wordpress, templates

i have something planned and i don't really know how and what kind of technologies i can use for it.
I want to create a website where I can use a CMS system or manually create a template. I make this template available to the user and he can change or edit content in it. For example, if I define a div that takes 20% of the page. Then the user can color the whole thing with a color code. Or if I define an H1, then the user can insert a title there. At the end he can export the whole thing as PDF.

Or

I create a contact form with many fields. The customer can fill in everything, e. g. address, telephone number . . . he sends this form and I define internally where the fields have to be positioned in a PDF. And especially how the whole thing should look like (CSS). Is that possible?

Is there such a thing already? A plugin for any CMS system like wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the first option will work.
You will need a form that the user will fill in.

You can use WordPress and a form builder plugin, such as [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/).

Now, regarding the exporting into PDF...do you have any programming knowledge?
If you can work with PHP, then you can use [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) library to export all data into a PDF file.
You can also see a similar thread here [Exporting form results from Contact form 7 to PDF (fPDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094291/exporting-form-results-from-contact-form-7-to-pdf-fpdf)

If you don't have any PHP knowledge then you will have to google and see if there is a plugin that does what you want. You may have to use a different form builder depending on that plugin.